# Как подключиться к общей папке на ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Добрый день, на ubuntu server есть share папка, не могу сообразить как к ней поучить доступ из linux mint ?

Comment: Через обзор сети вы видите сервер и share папку?

Comment: @zombic нет у  меня пишет "не может отобразить пути network"

Comment: а самба клиент установлен? (искать в репозиториях по samba и smb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

наверняка у вас есть доступ к серверу по протоколу *ssh*. тогда проще всего примонтировать каталог с сервера, пожалуй, с помощью [*sshfs*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS):

1. установите (один раз) на клиентской машине пакет *sshfs*:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install sshfs
   ```
2. создайте (один раз) на клиентской машине каталог с произвольным именем, куда будете монтировать каталог с сервера:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/какой-нибудь-пустой-каталог
   ```
3. предположим, что к серверу вы подключаетесь, например, командой `ssh user@server`, а путь к каталогу на сервере, например, `/share`. тогда примонтировать его можно так:

   ```
   $ sshfs user@server:/share ~/какой-нибудь-пустой-каталог
   ```
4. не забывайте отмонтировать каталог после того, как закончите работу с ним:

   ```
   $ fusermout -u ~/какой-нибудь-пустой-каталог
   ```

---

посмотреть, что сейчас примонтировано, можно программами `df` или `mount`.

Comment: это способ хорош, но у него есть "фатальный недостаток". Обычно на smb сервере для папок есть права доступа и специальный пользователь. Создавая каталог через ssh, потом нужно ещё поправлять права на файлы и каталоги.

Comment: @KoVadim, а откуда вдруг всплыла samba? не заметил упоминаний в вопросе.

Comment: Модуль​ телепатии подсказывает

Comment: Ну тогда уж и про NFS дописать.

Comment: @donRumata, больше ответов, хороших и разных!