# Визуализация веток в git

Tags: git

Начал работать с гитом на сайтах. Есть ли графические оболочки для гита, чтобы мог через них не с локальными проектами на гите работать, а удаленными, через ftp/sftp подключение?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=git+gui&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFt9uopKLhAhXylIsKHSOdBfEQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=937

Comment: А разве GIT GUI не с локальными проектами работает?

Comment: зависит от клиента

Comment: Так вопрос именно в этом был. Какие есть GUI?

Comment: Atlassian source tree, GitKraken

Comment: GUI для git уже есть во многих если не в  большинстве IDE.

Comment: как вариант: с ``sshfs`` - все

Comment: @StrangerintheQ пожалуйста не отправляйте людей просто так в поисковики. Ссылке стоит быть лишь дополнением.

Comment: *через ftp/sftp подключение* - ключевая фраза. Быстрее, что-то такое надо: https://www.deployhq.com/

Comment: Все стандартные GUI будут работать только с `https/ssh`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950107/git-push-into-production-ftp

Comment: дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/672300/178576